# How elements in tensor products shall be written as a linear combination of pure tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products

I was reading *An Introduction to the Representation Theory of Groups* by Emmanual Kowalski and came across some results (labelled Theorem 2.3.18) that ultimately rely on tensor products for general vector spaces that I'm not familiar with. The problems are:

Let $U$ and $V$ be (possibly infinite dimensional) vector spaces and $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis for $V$. Is it true that:

1. Any vector in $U\otimes V$ can be uniquely represented as $\sum_{i\in I}u_i\otimes v_i,u_i\in U$ (possibly infinite);
2. A linear transformation $T$ on $U\otimes V$ commutes with infinite sums, i.e. $T(\sum_{i\in I}u_i\otimes v_i)=\sum_{i\in I}T(u_i\otimes v_i)$?

Comment: In general vector spaces, infinite sums don't make any sense. In order to define an infinite sum you need some kind of topology. (which gives some kind of convergence) When we write $\sum_{i\in I} \alpha_i$, the meaning is that almost all terms are zeros, i.e $\alpha_i=0$ for all but finitely many values of $i$. So it is still a finite sum.

Comment: I know that, but I think the writer of the book wants to mean that $U\otimes V=\prod_{i\in I}U\otimes \operatorname{span}(v_i)$ and sums $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ where $a_i\in U\otimes \operatorname{span}(v_i)$ are supposed to formally add up components. Also for the particular interest of the topic, $T$ are defined to transform $U$ and $V$ independently (i.e. $T(a\otimes b)$=T_1(a)\otimesT_2(b) for some $T_1,T_2$) and maps $\{v_i\}$ to another basis for $V$, so the last sum is also treated as the formal sum properly.

Comment: Since $\prod_i \mathbf{R} v_i \cong (\bigoplus_i \mathbf{R}v_i)^*$, what you describe seems more like $U \otimes V^*$ than $U \otimes V$.

Answer (score 0):

When we write

$$ \sum_{i \in I} u_i \otimes v_i$$
we are implicitly assuming that only a finite amount of the terms $u_i \otimes v_i$ are non zero (therefore making the sum into a finite sum).

Therefore yes we do have
$$T\left(\sum_{i\in I}u_i\otimes v_i\right)=\sum_{i\in I}T(u_i\otimes v_i)$$
by linearity of $T$ for finite sums

The first part is also true. Indeed consider a basis $e_\alpha : \alpha \in A$ for $U$ then

$$ u \otimes v = \sum_i \sum_\alpha \lambda_i^\alpha (e_\alpha \otimes v_i) = \sum_i \underbrace{\left(\sum_\alpha  \lambda_i^\alpha e_\alpha\right)}_{u_i} \otimes v_i.$$